# Grails map values before sorting

Tags: database, sorting, grails, mapping, grails-orm

Is it at all possible to map or transform database query results before sorting them in Grails.
What I am trying to accomplish is this:

Lets say I have database column with values:

```
codes
 01,
 02,
 03,
 04,
```

And a function that is capable of mapping like this:

```
{
 01 -> B
 02 -> C
 03 -> A
 04 -> D
}
```

I would like the end result to be something like this;

```
[03, 01, 02, 04]
```

Id like it to sort using the values in the map and not by directly using the values in the database

Comment: Could you show some code on what you have?

Comment: your welcome @Eldridge 10 exp for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles upon this question.

The answer Orubel provided would work, but this means you are sorting data in memory.

One can also make an additional query but then you deal with I/O overhead.

Unfortunately there is no PERFECT answer for this issue, but when having to choose, the best solution is PROCESSING over I/O as processing will generally be faster than having to do it over a remote connection

The way I did it was I wrote it in SQL.
And to map/transform my data I used SQL CASE statements.(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)
And then placed that pice of SQL inside a WITH clause to query the data as needed. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/)

This adds I/O and isn't perfect but it was my solution

Comment: True but if you already have the data, you don't want to make another query. The I/O overhead of making another call and getting the data is more than a sort on data you already have onhand. You ALWAYS want to reduce I/O overhead first and THEN processing... and when given a choice between the two, if you already have the data, process locally rather than making another query.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could do this:

```
LinkedHashMap sorted = myMap.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
ArrayList myList = sorted.keySet() as ArrayList
```